# Is there a way to update the AVD after making changes without restarting it?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Like the title says, whenever I make any changes in the code I don't see the changes in the AVD. Is there a way to do this without closing the AVD and starting it again?

I'm using Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm that's definitely not the expected behavior. You should be able to execute your updated app from Eclipse. Check the ADB log and see if your APK is uploading and installing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed this behavior at times as well. In the ADB log it will state something like the activity is already started and has been brought to the front even though it was already on the screen. Not sure what the cause of this behavior is and it seems to happen randomly. I have dealt with this in the past by force stopping the app in the AVD or just uninstalling it. Sometimes pressing the home button on the AVD and then running the APP from eclipse seems to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Also, how do you force stop the app in the AVD or how do you uninstall the program? (Sorry I'm a bit new to this)

Comment: You can achieve these tasks the same way on an android device. Go into the "settings" Activity. Then go to "manage applications" Under running you will select your app (if it is running) and press Stop. If you want to uninstall the app, under "manage applications" go to downloaded and you should see your app. Then just press it and hit uninstall and you will be set. Uninstalling is useful when you want to wipe any data you stored on the AVD off of it.